# Difference between adobe printing properties in Linux and Windows

Tags: linux, windows, jasper-reports, dot-matrix

I work on Linux and I've made a report as the costumer wanted on iReport. It has some properties like "ignore pagination". I tested and retested a bunch of times and it has everything on its right position.

But my costumer has Windows and when I tried to print it on there, it's completely different. Even on adobe printing properties where I switch 2 attributes. One to not rotate and centralize and the other to get the page size of the document I've just created(because it makes only one page(ignore pagination attribute) and I'm printing on a Dot Matrix Printer, so it has that paper that "never ends")

Any idea of what could I do on Windows to print it correctly? What attribute on Windows would be the same as those that I'm reseting on Linux, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the drivers are using the same printer "language" on each system (I forget the technical name)- postscript, pcl, etc.. and version..  You can check the Linux system via CUPS and the Windows one via the printer driver properties.